# Swipe in element triggers swipe in outer element

Tags: angularjs

I have a HTML structure that looks something like this:

```
<div ng-swipe-right="outerSwipe()">

  ...

  <div ng-swipe-right="innerSwipe()">

    ...

  </div>

</div>
```

When I do a swipe in the inner div, `outerSwipe()` is also called.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to use something similar to `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: shortcut (inline two calls) `<div ng-swipe-right="innerSwipe(); $event.stopPropagation()">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  tymeJV suggested, you can add to your event handler [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method that prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

**Example:**

```
app.directive('ngSwipeRight', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { ngSwipeRight: '&' },
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            element.bind("mouseenter",function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
               //your logic here...
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/dmsw5/